# Laravel Validation for integers or specific word

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm creating a validation rule where `location` attribute can have any `integer` or a word `"all"` value.

For integer validation I use this rule:

```
'location' => 'required|integer'
```

and for a particular word I can use this rule:

```
'location' => ['required', Rule::in([all])]
```

How can apply both of rules together so that `location` can either be any integer or the word `"all"`?
Can regex be of any help here?

Comment: Use `'location' => ['required', 'regex:/^(?:\d+|all)$/']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'location' => [
        'required',
        'max:255',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if( is_int( $value ) || 'all' === $value ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

**But keep in mind:** If you send `integer` via form – you will receive `string`. And checking `is_int( $value )` will not be passed.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `regex` rule without `required` (if you don't mind a separate error message for empty fields):

```
'location' => ['regex:/^(?:\d+|all)$/']
```

This means the input value should be either `\d` or `all`.

Comment: I added this rule and it's working for all cases, except when I have a value say `"2"` then also it validates it to true.

Comment: You needed it to accept integers. So it accepts `2`. What's wrong here?

Comment: I'm not passing `2`. I'm passing 2 as string i.e `"2"` and it accepts that as well!

Comment: Do you mean double quotes exist?

Comment: While sending the data from front-end if I `parseInt(value)`, it is typecast as a integer. But if I remove the `parseInt()` javascript send the value as string and then `2` is received as `"2"`. Now regex is still validating it which is the issue here.

Comment: `preg_*` functions in PHP that deal with regular expressions receive a string as input value (they do an implicit cast if integers are given). So you may have some validations before that happens.